# Is there any name for HTML Entity Code Format

Tags: html

Does Like Below HTML Entity Code has three way to get result?

```
  &excl; //I want to know how to call this format
  &#x00021; // I want to know how to call this format
  &#33; // I want to know how to call this format
```

Every HTML Entity Code has three format to get result according [this link](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref). So, Is there any name for each format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#character-references):

> **Named character references**
>
> The ampersand must be followed by one of the names given in the named
>   character references section, using the same case. The name must be
>   one that is terminated by a U+003B SEMICOLON character (;).
>
> **Decimal numeric character reference**
>
> The ampersand must be followed by a U+0023 NUMBER SIGN character (#),
>   followed by one or more ASCII digits, representing a base-ten integer
>   that corresponds to a code point that is allowed according to the
>   definition below. The digits must then be followed by a U+003B
>   SEMICOLON character (;).
>
> **Hexadecimal numeric character reference**
>
> The ampersand must be followed by a U+0023 NUMBER SIGN character (#),
>   which must be followed by either a U+0078 LATIN SMALL LETTER X
>   character (x) or a U+0058 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X character (X), which
>   must then be followed by one or more ASCII hex digits, representing a
>   hexadecimal integer that corresponds to a code point that is allowed
>   according to the definition below. The digits must then be followed by
>   a U+003B SEMICOLON character (;).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
//  this format or call Entity Code
<p>I will display  &excl;</p>
<p>I will display &#x00021;</p>
<p>I will display &#33;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Comment: Sorry now you check @gehbiszumeis.